# raspberry pi と１個のWIFI端子を用いて、WIFI中継器の設定

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

やりたいこと：
ラズパイ・ゼロに1つのWIFI端子挿して、アクセスポイントにする同時に、家のWIFI信号を拾う。

イメージ：　家のWIFIルーター　＞＞　ラズパイゼロ　＞＞　他の端末（スマフォン、PC）

使用したもの：
１，ラズパイゼロ
２，WIFI端子 [バッファロー wli-uc-gnm2](http://buffalo.jp/product/wireless-lan/client/wli-uc-gnm2/)

参照したサイト：
１，[Raspberry Pi 3で、Wi-Fi アクセスポイントルータ - Qiita](http://qiita.com/mt08/items/f2e4f9d3b1ed00849e23)
２，[Raspberry Pi 2 + USB WiFiドングル2個で、Wi-Fi 中継器 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/mt08/items/4247894833bd4dcb27e2#_reference-27aa37c4be7f602667ff)

２に書いたように、２個のWIFI端子を使用すれば、やりたいことできるらしいが、仕様上wli-uc-gnm2は親機子機モード両方できるから購入したので、１つだけでできるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

動作は、親機(APモード)、または、子機(STAモード)のどちらか、一方だけです。同時に両方は対応してませんね。

Answer (score 0):

[WLI-UC-GNM2の仕様](http://buffalo.jp/product/wireless-lan/client/wli-uc-gnm2/#spec)をみると親子同時機能はWindowsですらサポートが限定されているので、それ以外のOSでは可能だとしても簡単にはできないと思います。